# What would a default getter and setter look like in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, virtual-attribute, attr-accessor

I know that I can write attr_accessor :tag_list to make a virtual attribute tag_list for an object in Rails. This allows there to be a tag_list attribute in forms for the object.

If I use attr_accessor :tag_list I can, in the model, perform actions on tag_list to pull and manipulate data from the form.

What I want to know is, instead of writing attr_accessor, how would I write a getter and setter that would replicate completely the default functionality of attr_accessor. EG:

```
def tag_list
    #what goes here
end
```

FYI I have tried

```
 def tag_list
     @tag_list
 end
```

This does NOT work.

Comment: the answer below is correct def tag_list is the accessor, it has to return a tag_list, so return @tag_list. Since ruby returns the last statement always, you can skip the return and just say \@tag_list to return \@tag_list.

Comment: Have you found your solution ? I have a similar problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198679/expose-a-has-many-relationship-through-a-single-text-field where my setter is never fired.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

[`attr_accessor`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor) is a built-in Ruby method and has no special meaning in the context ActiveRecord. `attr_accessor :tag_list` is basically equivalent to this code:

```
# getter
def tag_list
  @tag_list
end

# setter
def tag_list=(val)
  @tag_list = val
end
```

In ActiveRecord models, however, it could be that you want something like this:

```
def tag_list
  self[:tag_list]
end

def tag_list=(val)
  self[:tag_list] = val
end
```

There is a slight difference: With the first method, `obj[:tag_list]` doesn't use the same storage as your getter and setter. With the latter, it does.

#### Explanation of the getter/setter concept

In Ruby, the following two lines of code are equivalent

```
thing.blabla
thing.blabla()
```

Both call the method `blabla` of the object `thing` and evaluate to the last expression evaluated within that method. This means, you also don't need a `return` statement in the case of the above getter method, because the method simply returns the last expression in the method (`@tag_list`, the value of the instance variable).

Also, those two lines of code are equivalent:

```
thing.blabla=("abc")
thing.blabla = "abc"
```

Both call the method `blabla=` of the object `thing`. The special name with the `=` character can be used like any other method name.

The fact that *attributes*, as they are sometimes called, are in fact plain methods, you can also use some special logic transformed on the values before returning or accepting them. Example:

```
def price_in_dollar
  @price_in_euro * 0.78597815
end

def price_in_dollar=(val)
  @price_in_euro = val / 0.78597815
end
```

Comment: does it matter what I write for the argument in the setter? or is it just def tag_list=(whatever); @tag_list = whatever; end ?

Comment: @jay: No, it does not matter. Also, this is not Rails-specific, it's a Ruby thing. I edited your question to reflect this.

Comment: @jay: I updated the answer to add some extra information *WHY* this works.

Comment: niklas, sorry if i wasn't clear - i really need to make this work in a rails context. it's an html form that is submitting, and I can't retrieve the values from the attribute tag_list. This answer doesn't work.. I really would like to have tag_list accept from params[:object][:tag_list]

Comment: I think your edits are the right way to go... but I still can't access section_list from other methods in my model. Is it possible there is something else missing that the rails attr_accessor sets?

Comment: @jay: No, actually `attr_accessor` is not overridden by Rails (so it would be equivalent to my first code sample). Do you say that `attr_accessor` works okay but not that first code sample?

Comment: yes it does.. attr_accessor works find, your code does not - tag_list is nil in the case of trying to use your code

Comment: @jay: I can hardly believe that. Do you try to access the attribute with `obj[:tag_list]`? This will neither work with `attr_accessor` nor with the getter and setter I provided (I just tested it in a Rails console to be sure). Can you paste some (please only the relevant) code on pastie.org to show me the issue?

Comment: Hey Niklas, please know that I am very appreciative of your helping me with this. Thank you very much. I'm trying to be as cooperative as possible. I do not know what code to share. I write exactly the code you wrote into my model, and I have a validation   validates :tag_list, :presence => true. THis validation fails - indicating that tag_list never gets read by the controller on form submission

Comment: @jay: I cannot reproduce this, it should work. See http://pastie.org/3146488 for a working example under Rails 3.1.3. Sorry but it's late, I don't think I can spend more time on this, so could you please accept this answer? If you have any more problems, you probably want to open a new question with a some real code that causes you problems.

Comment: Actually there is one more thing that came to my mind: If you are using virtual attributes like these, their values will *not* be saved to the database, of course, as there is no matching DB column. Maybe you are setting a value, saving, and then loading the entry from some other place. This means that the value of the virtual attribute will be lost. Good night.

Answer (score 10):

When using ActiveRecord, this is the equivalent getter and setter versions:

```
def tag_list
  read_attribute(:tag_list)
end

def tag_list=(val)
  write_attribute(:tag_list, val)
end
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: yes - this is kind of, and I'm pretty sure it's part of the way to go.. It almost works, except for some reason tag_list can't be accessed in other methods in my model still. Is there something else that attr_accessor does that is missing here?

Comment: Are you doing `tag_list = whatever`? Because if so, you're not invoking the setter, you're initializing a local variable. Instead you would do `self.tag_list = whatever`. Alternatively, if you're having difficulty getting it to read values from the form, check if you're preventing its mass assignment by not adding it to an `attr_accessible ...` list.

Comment: To note, I had an issue with minitest where I would get "can't write unknown attribute..." errors when using setter methods defined like this (with `write_attribute`). When I just switched the setter to setting an instance variable named after the virtual attribute, both tests and my web application worked fine.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999460/rails-4-minitest-testing-virtual-attributes

Answer (score 0):

```
Notice the code below is in the [Helpers] path. Helpers are now included for                            
all [Controllers] to work from when instantiated.

module SettergettersHelper

#TODO Wayne 
mattr_accessor :nameport
#TODO Wayne Mattingly the code below was replaced BY ABOVE 
#TODO and not depricatable RAILS 4.2.3

# def nameport
#   @nameport 
# end

# def nameport=(nameport)
#   @nameport = nameport 
#end
end

*Getter from Accounts Controller:*
def index
   @portfolio_name = nameport     
end
*Setter from Portfolio Controller:*
def show
    @portfolio_name = @portfolio_name.portfolio_name #from database call
    SettergettersHelper.nameport =  @portfolio_name # set attribute
end
```